# После добавления в приложение рекламного баннера admob приложение крашится

Tags: android, admob

Приложение без ошибок загружается на устройство, но вылетает сразу после запуска.
Перепробовал все известные в интернете методы добавления результат такой же.

```
10-07 21:07:08.199 6194-6194/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:09.176 6206-6206/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:22.788 1391-1391/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package yo.app.free by user request.
10-07 21:07:22.788 1391-1391/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package yo.app.free by user request.
10-07 21:07:22.861 1391-1391/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package yo.app.free by user request.
10-07 21:07:27.130 6359-6359/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:27.134 6357-6357/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:28.404 6381-6381/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:29.324 6392-6392/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:31.773 6403-6403/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:32.355 6415-6415/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:32.978 6429-6429/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:33.583 6442-6442/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:34.174 6454-6454/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:34.764 6466-6466/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:35.375 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
10-07 21:07:35.412 6478-6478/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:37.536 6491-6491/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:38.149 6502-6502/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:38.820 6513-6513/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:40.163 6524-6524/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:40.450 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.451 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.451 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.452 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.452 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.452 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.453 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.453 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.453 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.454 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.454 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.454 1391-1606/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.483 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.484 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.484 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.484 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.484 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.485 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.485 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.485 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.485 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.486 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.486 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:40.486 3501-3517/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.381 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.381 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.382 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.382 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.382 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.383 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.383 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.384 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.384 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.384 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.385 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:41.385 1391-1524/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
10-07 21:07:42.396 713-713/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1362791904.tmp: No such file or directory
10-07 21:07:42.398 1391-1524/? E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
10-07 21:07:42.625 2145-2433/? E/Launcher.AllAppsList: Can't load postion for app Бутылочка +
10-07 21:07:42.959 6617-6617/? E/SystemUpdater-LocalAppManager: getDetailAppInfo null: ru.infernal93.butilochka
10-07 21:07:43.042 26823-26823/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
10-07 21:07:43.696 6702-6702/? E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/memtrack.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:43.768 3583-3594/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
10-07 21:07:43.894 6790-6790/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.027 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for ru.yandex.disk.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.029 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for org.stepic.droid.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.031 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.appmk.book.AOUKZFJHQIIANWBPF.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.033 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for ru.hh.android.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.035 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for ru.rambler.lenta.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.037 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.lessons.tree.myapplication.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.107 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for ru.habrahabr.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.110 6748-6748/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.mobilesrepublic.appygeek.MetricaContentProvider
10-07 21:07:44.133 6820-6820/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.181 6827-6827/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.223 6832-6832/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.270 6837-6837/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.317 6840-6840/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.358 6845-6845/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.400 6848-6848/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.441 6851-6851/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.483 6854-6854/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.525 6859-6859/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@ru.infernal93.butilochka-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
10-07 21:07:44.566 6617-6668/? E/SystemUpdater-DataParser: [AppList] JSON : list is null
                                                           No value for miuiApp
10-07 21:07:44.888 6773-6877/ru.infernal93.butilochka E/HAL: Dawei load: module=/system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
10-07 21:07:44.950 6617-6871/? E/SystemUpdater-DataParser: [AppList] JSON : list is null
                                                           No value for listApp
10-07 21:07:45.661 6617-6841/? E/SystemUpdater-ConnectionRSA: get key exception : com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.DecoderException: unable to decode base64 string: invalid characters encountered in base64 data
10-07 21:07:45.685 6617-6841/? E/SystemUpdater-AppActivateStatService: upload app active stat Success!
10-07 21:07:47.828 3583-3594/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
10-07 21:07:49.600 6773-7045/ru.infernal93.butilochka E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-07 21:08:35.374 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
10-07 21:08:42.188 2287-9506/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.188 2287-9506/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.298 2287-9504/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.298 2287-9504/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.396 2287-2611/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.396 2287-2611/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.444 2287-2299/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:42.444 2287-2299/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed
10-07 21:08:44.780 7890-7979/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for metok
10-07 21:08:44.864 7890-7985/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for metok
10-07 21:08:50.042 7890-7897/? E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
10-07 21:08:50.046 7890-7897/? E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void dalvik.system.CloseGuard.close()' on a null object reference
                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:113)
                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.finalize(FileInputStream.java:140)
                                             at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:229)
                                             at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:216)
                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-07 21:08:57.019 8158-8158/? E/GcmReceiver: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
10-07 21:08:57.021 8158-8158/? E/GcmReceiver: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
10-07 21:09:03.855 6684-6717/? E/Crashlytics: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/ru.hinews/settings
                                              com.crashlytics.android.internal.aD: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.204.4.24 (port 443) after 10000ms
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.b(SourceFile:1391)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.f(SourceFile:1664)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.d(SourceFile:1576)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.c(SourceFile:1590)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aO.a(SourceFile:63)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:48)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:36)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aS.c(SourceFile:125)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:884)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:54)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.t.a(SourceFile:839)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                               Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/54.204.4.24 (port 443) after 10000ms
                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                                                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:79)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:342)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:331)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:150)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:192)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getHeaderField(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:190)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:1912)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.c(SourceFile:1590) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aO.a(SourceFile:63) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:48) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:36) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aS.c(SourceFile:125) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:884) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:54) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.t.a(SourceFile:839) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13) 
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
10-07 21:09:35.376 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
10-07 21:10:24.220 6684-6718/? E/Crashlytics: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/ru.hinews/settings
                                              com.crashlytics.android.internal.aD: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/174.129.247.236 (port 443) after 10000ms
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.b(SourceFile:1391)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.f(SourceFile:1664)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.d(SourceFile:1576)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.c(SourceFile:1590)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aO.a(SourceFile:63)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:48)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:36)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aS.c(SourceFile:125)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.D.a(SourceFile:30)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.E.a(SourceFile:93)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                               Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/174.129.247.236 (port 443) after 10000ms
                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
                                                  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                                                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:79)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:342)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:331)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:150)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:192)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getHeaderField(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:190)
                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:1912)
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.c(SourceFile:1590) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aO.a(SourceFile:63) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:48) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:36) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aS.c(SourceFile:125) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.D.a(SourceFile:30) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.E.a(SourceFile:93) 
                                                  at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13) 
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
10-07 21:10:35.377 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
10-07 21:10:38.952 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.
10-07 21:10:39.618 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.
10-07 21:10:39.631 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: handleResponse: num Cached results in this fragment:1
10-07 21:10:39.632 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: More data: 0, firstScanIdInPatch: 1812, lastProcessedScanId: -1
10-07 21:10:39.632 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: gscan_get_cached_results: starting counter: 0
10-07 21:10:39.632 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: gscan_get_cached_results: cached_results[0].num_results: 1 
10-07 21:10:39.637 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.
10-07 21:10:39.682 1391-2883/? E/LocSvc_libulp: E/int ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic run due to both engines are OFF 
10-07 21:11:15.543 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.
10-07 21:11:16.204 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.
10-07 21:11:16.208 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: handleResponse: num Cached results in this fragment:1
10-07 21:11:16.209 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: More data: 0, firstScanIdInPatch: 1813, lastProcessedScanId: -1
10-07 21:11:16.209 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: gscan_get_cached_results: starting counter: 0
10-07 21:11:16.209 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: gscan_get_cached_results: cached_results[0].num_results: 1 
10-07 21:11:16.213 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.
10-07 21:11:16.239 1391-2883/? E/LocSvc_libulp: E/int ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic run due to both engines are OFF 
10-07 21:11:35.375 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
10-07 21:11:53.009 1391-1689/? E/native: do suspend false
10-07 21:11:53.791 11038-11090/? E/AviaryCdsService: LAZY Execution..
10-07 21:12:35.375 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
10-07 21:13:35.375 1391-2099/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLocation*, izat_manager::IzatLocationStatus) line 171 "1"
```

Comment: не то пальто. Не компиляции лог нужен, а запуска приложения. Catlog

Comment: А что выложить debug или error, не уверен, что все вместится сюда

Comment: То, что красным выкладывайте

Comment: и вот еще 10-07 21:16:16.951 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: handleResponse: num Cached results in this fragment:1
10-07 21:16:16.951 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: More data: 0, firstScanIdInPatch: 1814, lastProcessedScanId: -1
10-07 21:16:16.951 1391-1711/? E/WifiHAL: gscan_get_cached_results: starting counter: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо. Я разобрался, нужно было в xml разметке ширину сделать android:layout_width="match_parent" не влезала реклама в экран. Зато научился пользоваться CatLog и Android Monitor